# Is it possible to get a variable (uint) of the child contract, in a parent contract? [Solidity]

Tags: variables, solidity, parent, contract, uint

I'm making a system that adds a fee to every transaction of my ERC20 token. 
I have two files, **wiseth_v1.sol** and **ERC20Mod.sol** written in Solidity. 
**ERC20.sol** is a modification of the [ERC20.sol Openzeppelin's contract](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol). 
**wiseth_v1.sol** first lines:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "./ERC20Mod.sol";

contract Wiseth is ERC20, Ownable {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    uint deployDate;
    uint daHour;
    bool isPassed;
    bytes32 num_type;
    uint public percentage;
```

As you can see, the parent contract is **ERC20Mod.sol** and its child is **wiseth_v1.sol** (the true token's script). 
The owner of the contract sets the fee's percentage with this function (**wiseth_v1.sol**):

```
function setFirstPercentageFee(uint256 fee) external onlyOwner {
        percentage = fee;
    }
```

And this is the `transferFrom` function of the transaction on **ERC20Mod.sol**:

```
function transferFrom(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) public virtual override returns (bool) {

        uint256 fee = (amount.mul(percentage)).div(10000);
        uint256 total = amount.sub(fee);

        address spender = _msgSender();
        _spendAllowance(from, spender, amount);
        _transfer(from, to, total);
        return true;
    }
```

When calculating the fee `uint256 fee = (amount.mul(percentage)).div(10000);` i need to take the "percentage" uint256 from **wiseth_v1.sol**, how do i do that? Any help is appreciated. (I don't want to put the **wiseth_v1.sol** code in **ERC20Mod.sol**, i want to keep them separate. Thanks.

I searched on Google but only found how to take parent variables in its child. I use remix.ethereum.org

Answer (score 0):

I think that whole logic of inheritance is that child inherit from parent, but you want to do opposite. Maybe you should define your own variable "percentage" in ERC20Mod.sol and manually set it when needed.

Comment: So "reverse inheritance" isn't possible? I will sure try to merge the two files..